# Queue probability of people standing in different positions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

n people ($n\ge 3$), from which we distinguish person X,Y and Z, are arranged in a randomly ordered queue. Find the probability that  X is standing in front of Y (not necessarily in neighbouring positions), given that Z is standing right behind Y.

I do not know how to solve that, i know that's conditional probability, but what should i do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we think about a clever way, let us **grind it out**. Let $B$ be the event Z is right behind Y, and let $A$ be the event $X$ is (somewhere) in front of Y. We compute $\Pr(A\mid B)$ in the usual way, dividing $\Pr(A\cap B)$ by $\Pr(B)$.

First we find $\Pr(B)$. There are $(n)(n-1)$ equally likely ways to choose the positions of Y and Z. In $n-1$ of these, Z is right behind Y, for a probability that simplifies to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Now we find $\Pr(A\cap B)$. There are $n(n-1)(n-2)$ equally likely ways to choose the positions of our three heroes. If Z and Y are at the left end, there are $n-2$ positions for X. If Z is in the second position from the left, there are $n-3$ legal positions for X. And so on up to Z being third from the right end, when X has $1$ position available. That gives a total of $(n-2)+(n-1)+\cdots+1$, which is $\frac{(n-2)(n-1)}{2}$. Divide by $(n)(n-1)(n-2)$, and we get $\frac{1}{2n}$.

That gives a conditional probability that simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Remark:** The answer is screaming that there is a better way. Do it!

Comment: where does this sum for $P(A \cap B)$ comes from, because i do not understand it? I am talking about the sum of X combinations

Comment: Are you talking about the evaluation of $(n-2)+(n-3)+\cdots +1$?  Maybe it will be more familiar if we reverse the sum to get $1+2+\cdots+(n-3)+(n-2)$. Now let $k=n-2$. We are looking at the sum of the arithmetic progression $1+2+\cdots+k$. By a formula you may remember, the sum is $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$.

Comment: thank you appreciate your time

Comment: You are welcome. Now for the simple way, note that essentially we have right-left symmetry.  I can add a few lines later to give that much "nicer" argument.